# Maven clean won't delete copied resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

To make my life easier, I configured my maven to put my deployed application in a different folder (`/deploy`) than the default (so it doesn't mix with `classes/`, `surefire-reports` directories and so forth). It works fine, except that when I try to run `mvn clean`, it only deletes the jar and copied dependencies, but NOT the copied resources.

**UPDATE** It appears they are being deleted, but then get placed back immediately. It appears to be related to using Eclipse and `Build Automatically`, but I'm not sure why changing Maven's configuration would have this effect on Eclipse. **END UPDATE**

**UPDATE 2** At the present moment, none of the answers are correct. This problem clearly has little to do with the `deploy` directory; it seems that *maven-resources-plugin* makes Eclipse copy resources as part of *Build Automatically*. But I'm not sure how to turn this off without stopping using *maven-resources-plugin*, and without stopping using *Build Automatically* I will give the bounty to someone who can explain how to do this. **END UPDATE 2**

Anyway, my directory looks something like this:

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
|   |-- main
|   |   |-- java
|   |   `-- resources
|   |       |-- script.sh
|   |       `-- config
|   |           `-- app.properties
|   `-- test
|       |-- java
|       `-- resources
`-- deploy
    |-- my-app.jar <----- This gets deleted correctly
    |-- lib        <----- This gets deleted correctly
    |   |-- dependency1.jar     <----- This gets deleted correctly
    |   |-- dependency2.jar     <----- This gets deleted correctly
    |-- config     <----- This DOES NOT get deleted correctly
    |   `-- app.properties      <----- This DOES NOT get deleted correctly
    `-- script.sh  <----- This DOES NOT get deleted correctly
```

Here's my `pom` snippet:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.jar.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
                <packageName>my.main</packageName>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <excludes>
            <exclude><!-- the files I don't want in my jar --></exclude>
        </excludes>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/deploy</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/deploy/lib</outputDirectory>
                <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/deploy</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>deploy</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @Ben why did you delete the [tag:clean] tag?

Comment: Because it isn't specific enough; how many languages have a `clean` function etc? It will instantly become overwhelmed by people using it for the wrong reason. I guess you could add a `[maven-clean]` or `[mvn-clean]` if you prefer but please don't use something so generic.

Comment: The default directory has all this extra crap in it, I want to make a directory that is just the jar and other files. Once the pom is set up I don't have to touch it anymore

Comment: By "default directory" do you mean "target"?  Are you aware that target/web-app-name-version/ already contains just the web app in exploded (unzipped) form?  And of course that directory is already cleaned automatically.

Comment: @Keith A) This is not a web application, B) Yes, I mean `target`, C) I have other configuration files in subdirectories, D) I actively don't want to use one-jar or similar, I have a libs directory, these all get mixed in with `maven-archiver`, `maven-status`, `surefire`, `test-classes`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, read the question too fast.  Hmm, seems like a bug in the clean plugin.  Unless something (IDE, another plugin) is copying config *after* each clean.  Maybe add the version of maven you are using to the question, in case anyone wants to try reproducing this.

Comment: @Keith copying after each clean occurred to me, but my `resources` plugin is set to phase `install`, so I can't imagine that's it.

Comment: With your config, clean plugin should clean everything under the deploy directory, at least under Windows (tested). Can you launch mvn clean -X to see exactly what happens?

Comment: this is why you should note deviate from the standard conventions that Maven uses, customizing it is fraught with complications.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Again the problem is not really maven but seems to be actually m2eclipse. Also, moving to a directory under target **doesn't work either**

Comment: eclipse basically uses your maven pom file to build the application, and so may be there is some problem in your pom file and not with the eclipse plugin.

Comment: and if you run mvn from command line? Just to test the hypotesis of eclipse interference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If question is `how to disable eclipse to run specific plugin` than you can put in under specific profile that is active by default

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>not-eclipse</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
             ...
        </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
  ...
</project>
```

and place `! not-eclipse` in profile settings of eclipse project

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that last part in a bit more detail? I don't know to where you refer.

Comment: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.ru/2011/11/how-to-activate-maven-profile-inside.html#.UieA367249Q here example how to activate profile, with `!` profile will be deactivated

Comment: Also ,check this http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#How_to_configure_Maven_project_to_use_separate_output_folders_in_Eclipse

Answer (score 7):

Stick to the Maven way and put your `deploy` directory under `${basedir}/target` then your problem will fix itself.  You can remove the custom plugin configuration for the clean plugin as well.

Comment: Well, I have new evidence now. Maven clean CREATED config and datalogger after I changed the pom. Maybe my goal for copy-resources is wrong?

Comment: To everyone upvoting this answer, this DOESN'T WORK

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I've used this approach extensively.

Comment: Because Eclipse keeps recopying the files even after a clean

Comment: Then change the phase of the custom plugin executions to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

In your place I'd stick to the "Maven way". If you want a place where only your jar is stored do `mvn install` and refer to `~/.m2/repository/groupId/artifactId`, if you want your jar packed with its configuration files and/or dependencies use the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Note that Eclipse's automated rebuilding takes place also with the default configuration. Personally I let Eclipse handle its workspace the way it wants and perform command line builds in a separate check-out or by meeans of [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/node).

Comment: Which Eclipse release are you using?

Comment: Kepler. With embedded m2eclipse 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Your issue reproduces on a sample project with resources. Run As -> Maven Clean has the output as mentioned later which only covers the cleaning up.

Although the latest version does not offer this [screen](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/preferences.html#preferences-sect-maven-preferences), I'm guessing the goal `process-resources` still runs which would copy the resources to your output directory on running any Maven task.

I wonder why, when the Sonatype book mentions it, the plugin still doesn't show those options.

In a previous project of mine we used to remove the `process-resources` from **Goals to run when updating project configuration** to avoid resource processing as major tasks were handled from commandline.

Hope this helps.

P.S: *I don't think your issue has anything to do with you changing the deploy directory.*

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 14:14:56+0530)
Maven home: C:\projects\workspace\abc\EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.7.0_04, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jre7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from EMBEDDED\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\stackoverflow\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\stackoverflow\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Users\stackoverflow\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project abc:abc:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: abc:abc:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       abc:abc:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <directory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <excludeDefaultDirectories default-value="false">${clean.excludeDefaultDirectories}</excludeDefaultDirectories>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <followSymLinks default-value="false">${clean.followSymLinks}</followSymLinks>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <reportDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${clean.skip}</skip>
  <testOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <verbose>${clean.verbose}</verbose>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ abc ---
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
...
Lots of such lines
...
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@769fe666]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) directory = C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target
[DEBUG]   (f) excludeDefaultDirectories = false
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) followSymLinks = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) reportDirectory = C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target\site
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) testOutputDirectory = C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target\test-classes
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target\classes
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target\test-classes
[DEBUG] Skipping non-existing directory C:\projects\rollbase2.0workspace\abc\target\site
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.693s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 01 16:38:36 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the only answer that seems to be on the right track. Unfortunately because it's not really an "answer" I hesitate to give the bounty here, but certainly it's the frontrunner.

Comment: Agreed @durron597. Couple of friends of mine have gone through the same trouble. Why the UI of the plugin is different from the documentation beats me.

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine, except that when I try to run mvn clean, it only deletes the jar and copied dependencies, but NOT the copied resources.

I realize that this is an older question, but it is the first question I found when investigating the same issue experienced by the OP. This is provided as a definitive answer for anyone else engaged in similar *literary research* as to why this behavior is observed.

> It appears they are being deleted, but then get placed back immediately

When run from the command line `mvn clean` removes all build artifacts by deleting the `target` directory. However, when run from within Eclipse, it appears that `target` is not deleted. Furthermore, if non-default resources are defined such as those presented in the question, it appears that they are not deleted.

This is just an illusion and is the result of two distinct tasks. The first, `mvn clean` deletes the entire `target` directory. The second task is as a result of **Project → Build Automatically** causing M2E Builder execution of `compile` and `test-compile` phases during full and/or incremental workspace builds.

A prerequisite of these phases is the execution of several other phases such as `generate-resources` and `process-resources` (see [Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)). These in turn, will cause the execution of resource goals such as those defined by the OP.

The end result of automatic builds is that the `target` directory is recreated containing:

- OP's custom resources.
- `test-classes` containing compiled code from `src/test/java` and resources from `src/test/resources`
- `test-classes` containing compiled code and resources from `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources`, respectively.

Eclipse does not show `classes` and `test-classes` folders since they are marked as output folders (see **Properties → Java Build Path → Source**). However, since the OP's custom resources are not output directories, they are displayed, resulting in the illusion that `mvn clean` does not remove them.

If there is doubt, one can verify this by disabling the `Java output folders` option under **Customize View... → Filters** in the **Project Explorer** view. It should be noted that this filtering option is not available in the **Package Explorer** view. A simpler verification is to run `mvn clean` and examine the contents of the project directory via the operating system's console or file explorer.

Lastly, running `mvn clean` from the command line, will verify that it does delete the `target` directory as expected; only to reappear once Eclipse's automatic build kick in after changes in the IDE. In general, it is a good idea to build projects from the command line once in a while to ensure that the build configuration is IDE agnostic.

Comment: I did come to realize this eventually, and while this is very useful information for those reading this question, it doesn't really answer the question "what should I do if I find myself in this situation" (unlike my accepted answer)

Comment: @durron597 Thank you for the feedback. I did realize that you changed the focus of your question in Update #2, which should have been a new question. The goal of my answer is to explain the whys and hows of the *titled* question and its original description for anyone that came upon it as I did. The least of my concerns is whether this is accepted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following fileset to the maven-clean-plugin section

```
<fileset>
    <directory>${basedir}/deploy/config</directory>
</fileset>
```

Comment: I will try that but it won't solve the other problem. See my above edit to the file structure.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `Maven Builder` is getting invoked from Eclipse, which is inturn populating files again. I guess you can try disabling Maven builder and Maven nature for your project in eclipse to see if it solves problem.

To disable Eclipse Maven builder this go to

```
Eclipse Project Properties -> Builders -> Maven builder
```

Disabling eclipse maven nature
[image]

All I am saying is problem is due to eclipse-maven integration and not maven

Comment: This would probably solve the "problem", but it would also break everything else.

Comment: break what? Maybe I can suggest solution to it.

Comment: well I am not asking you to turn off maven. I am asking you to disable maven nature from eclipse. you can still execute maven commands on project structure.